# Subsonic - how to generate tables which have YYYYMM suffix

Tags: c#, subsonic

.Net 2.0, Vs 2005, Subsonic 2.2, New to subsonic

I have tables that are created each month with a YYYYMM suffix. Can a template (or something) to access tables like these be generated?

Each month a new one is added so it's no use generating the ones I already have since the code won't work when I need to access a new one.

I need a template or such for these kind of tables that I can pass the YYYYMM suffix into it as I access it rather than by class name. It seems the default subsonic tables work with parameterless constructors.

Any way to get around this?